# what's the difference of drawing model when hardware acceleration is true and false?

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I have a custom LinearLayout and custom TextView, the TextView locates at center. see the xml layout:

```
<com.example.androidtest.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff0000"
tools:context="com.example.androidtest.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<com.example.androidtest.MyTextView 
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:text="abc"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#4400ff00"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    />

</com.example.androidtest.MyLinearLayout>
```

I override `onDraw` method in both classes, and add a log ouput like "onDraw in MyTextView called".
And I set a `onClickListener` on the TextView within which i call `invalidate()`.

```
    tv=(MyTextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    System.out.println("onClick");
            tv.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Example 1: Hardware acceleration: **true/false**, TextView background color: **0xff00ff00**    result: ...->onClick->onDraw in MyTextView..

(Please note that the background color becomes translucent now)

Example 2: Hardware acceleration: **false**, TextView background color: **0x4400ff00**   result: ...->onClick->**onDraw in MyLinearLayout**->onDraw in MyTextView..

Example 3: Hardware acceleration: **true**, TextView background color: **0x4400ff00**    result: ...->onClick->onDraw in MyTextView..

question 1: the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#model) says that in soft rendering pipeline, ANY view in the view hierachy that intersects with the dirty region will also be redrawn. So according example 1, is it already optimized ?

question 2: in example 3, why the `onDraw` method in MyLinearLayout isn't called? how could it be? Doesn't it need to draw the parent first and then do alpha blending with TextView?

Comment: q2: with hardware acceleration the layout view will be drawn from the displaylist and the onDraw shouldnt be called only the onDraw of the invalidated view shall be recalled.

Comment: yes， i realized it. There should be a hardware texture backing the parent up.